# Многоязычность сайта

Tags: php, локализация

Подскажите, как без использования Mysql сделать на сайте другой язык? Как это можно реализовать, подскажите или подбросьте пример. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: На Kohana Framework это очень удобно реализовано

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вопрос из разряда вытекающих в последствие новых вопросов. Вариантов очень много, но раз вы хотите на PHP:

Создаем массив $translates. Весь текст, который будет подвергаться переводу - заносим в массив по языковым ключам и выводим в зависимости от языка, который устанавливается куками.

```
$language = $_COOKIE['language'];
$translates = array(
  'sitename' => array('ru' => 'ХэшКод', 'en' => 'Hashcode')
);
// ... bla-bla-bla
<title><?=$translates['sitename'][$language];?></title>
```

Ну и делаем страницу, которая будет изменять куки через интерфейс сайта.

Естественно можно придумать гораздо больше решений, в примере можно в несколько раз сделать проще, например придумать функции для вывода, но опять же, это только набросок, решений здесь очень много.

Answer (score 3):

Другой вариант: есть 2 файла.
1ый файл:

```
<?
$url = "Адрес сайта";
$hash = "Хешкод";
?>
```

2ой файл

```
<?
$url = "URL";
$hash = "Hashcode";
?>
```

Потом берем значение из $_COOKIE['language']; и подключаем файл:

```
if($_COOKIE['language'] == "en"){
   include "en.php";
}
else{
   include "rus.php";
}
```